# COM: method parameter attribute always needed?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl

I have and ATL simple object interface named ISimpleCom.
This object implement connection point.
I was wondering why "ordinary" COM method parameters have to be prefixed with and attribute but an event method does not ?

ISimpleCom method:

`[id(1)] HRESULT Calculate([in] VARIANT_BOOL a_bFireEvent, [out,retval] LONG* a_lTotalMarks);`

_ISimpleComEvents method(the event "signature", note "a_lTotalMark"s param is not attributed):
`[id(1)] HRESULT TotalMarks(LONG a_lTotalMarks);`

```
Fire_TotalMarks(12); <-- will fire the event in my case to C# manage code
```

Comment: They should still be attributed, it isn't clear how you used the wizard.  Not that critical, [in] is the default and always ought to be for a connection point since you can't count on the client code actually subscribing the event.

Comment: `[in]` and/or `[out]` have to be there because otherwise marshaling has no idea which way to carry the value on the way between parties.

Comment: @RomanR. you'd be surprised but marshaling works fine without any attributes set for connection point method parameters. I don't know how but it works, even for more "complex" object such as SAFEARRAY marshaling to Managed code (in my case C#) works fine !

Comment: @HansPassant. I followed a tutorial to create connection point method using the wizard. According to that tutorial they did not tick any method parameter attribute (int/out/retval) just selected the type and input a name. That's how "TotalMarks" "a_lTotalMarks" ended up without any attribute. But as a mentioned above it works just fine.That's why I was curious why it works...

Comment: This is how it works exactly: [The `[in]` attribute is applied to a parameter by default when no directional parameter attribute is specified.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367051.aspx)

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks! I knew it has something to do with defaults.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter attribute magic is [explained on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367051.aspx):

> The [in] attribute has a converse attribute, [out], which indicates
>   that a parameter is to be returned from the called procedure to the
>   calling procedure. The [in] and [out] attributes are known as
>   directional parameter attributes because they specify the direction in
>   which parameters are passed. A parameter can be defined as [in],
>   [out], or [in, out].
>
> The [in] attribute identifies parameters that are marshaled by the
>   client stub for transmission to the server.
>
> The [in] attribute is applied to a parameter by default when no
>   directional parameter attribute is specified.

Which is briefly the following:

- parameters are `in`, `out` and `in/out`, directionless parameter does not make sense so if you omit the attribute, `[in]` still applies; you don't have to put `[in]` but it's a good idea to do it for clarity
- these parameters define the direction of parameter value transfers when it comes to marshaling and and otherwise transmission when the call assumes some transit on the caller/callee way

Answer (score 0):

The attributes in COM are hints to the COM runtime about optimizations that it can make.  For instance, if a param is marked as `[in]`, the runtime knows it doesn't have to allocate any memory for a return value.  If `[out]` it only worries about the memory as a return value. 
In short, it helps the code run more efficiently so it's always a good idea to use them (whether connection point or method param).

It also prevents a runtime error. For example, a called function setting a value to a param not marked as `[out]` would not get the value it was expecting back to the calling function because the runtime would not know to marshal it back.

Comment: So according to your post this attributes can be neglected ? BTW if your COM side method have LONG* as a parameter without [out] attribute and you'll call that function from managed code such as C# (C# will interpret this parameter as `ref int`) and make an assignment it will be marshaled back to COM.

Comment: `[in]` allows for more efficient marshalling.  `[out]` and `[retval]` are necessary (C# may make an assumption that other languages would not for your example, above).

Comment: If I get this correct connection point method parameters should always be attributed with [in].

Comment: It is recommended and is a consistent way to program.